# How to unwrap tuple with CompactMap in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, tuples, option-type

I'm kickbell.

I usually use `CompactMap` to remove `nil`.

for example,

```swift
let wrappedArray = [nil, 2, 6, "ddf"].compactMap{ $0 }

wrappedArray //[2, 6, "ddf"]
```

and, i want same result the tuple. but, it not working i expected.

what should i do ?

plz reply when you have time.

thanks for your help.

```swift
let tuple: [(Bool?, Int?)] = [
  (state: true, value: 3),
  (state: true, value: nil),
  (state: nil, value: 55),
  (state: false, value: nil)
]

let wrappedTuple = tuple.compactMap{$0}

wrappedTuple
//[(.0 Optional(true), .1 3),
//(.0 Optional(true), nil),
//(nil, .1 55),
//(.0 Optional(false), nil)]
```

Comment: What result do you expect?  What should happen to a tuple that has a nil element?  Should the entire tuple be dropped from the array if either the state or value is `nil`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `let wrappedTuple = tuple.compactMap{$0}` works if you had (note the last ?):

```
        let tuple: [(Bool?, Int?)?] = [  // <-- here
          (state: true, value: 3),
          (state: true, value: nil),
          (state: nil, value: 55),
          (state: false, value: nil),
          nil,
          nil
        ]
```

What you may want (with your original tuple) is to use filter, such as:

```
 let wrappedTuple = tuple.filter{ $0.0 != nil && $0.1 != nil }
```

and adjust the logic as you desire.

If you want non-optionals in the tuples as the results, try this:

```
 let wrappedTuple = tuple.filter{ $0.0 != nil && $0.1 != nil }.map{ ($0.0!,$0.1!) }
```

You could still use `compactMap` like this. It really depends on what
you want to achieve.

```
 let wrappedTuple = tuple.compactMap{$0.0}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. workingdog.

I would like to ask another question,

1.
Why did you put the last `nil` of your example code?


2.
Why Apple doesn't support compactMap for tuples? I think that it is not much different from other data structures, so it is.

thank you.

Comment: last nil, what code example are you referring to? As I mentioned, `compactMap` 
does work on array of tuples, it will "remove" any nil from your array. 
It does not work on the content of the tuple itself. It is up to you 
to determine what you want the results to be.

Comment: Ah.. now i understand. what i said is, i was why you added nil to your tuple. `compactMap` works for arrays of tuples, but not for the tuple contents... unsderstand. thank you.